# Is it possible to load remote pdf using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, embed, pdf.js

Having trouble making remote PDF show up on web page using PDF.js - I don't want to use iframe,just have the html show up on the actual page, is this possible, if so what is easiest most simple basic code for guy who hasn't used javascript much.

Comment: If _pdf.js_ is using _AJAX_ (which it probably is) to load in the document, then you need to set up _CORS_ on the server hosting the _pdf_

Comment: It isn't doing anything because I can't figure out how to do it, how do you use it to load the pdf using Ajax? Because I actually do have CORS set up I just don't know how to use pdf.js and the docs only talk about iframes.

Comment: Take a look at their hello world example https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js